# Drag & Drop to every label javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Here is what I have now:

```
Label [][] abc = new Label[100][100];
```

After initiating them all, I have assigned them to AnchorPane. Now I would like to detect every abc if there are any things drop on it.

```
//For one label only, I would do this:
Label abc = new Label("ABC");
abc.setOnDragDropped(new DragDroppedEventHandler());
```

Is there any way to do for all Label abc [100][100]???

I have something to add:
If I have lots of lambda things / anonymous inner class things like this:

```
abc.setOnDragExited((DragEvent event) -> {});
```

It seems I can only put the above code into a for loop in order to make it work.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
    for (int j .....) {
        Label target = abc[i][j];
        target.setOnDragDropped(new DragDroppedEventHandler());
        target.setOnDragExited((DragEvent event) -> {...});
    }
}
```

What I am asking for is that is there any proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this,

```
for(int i=0; i<abc.length; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<abc[i].length;j++) {
        abc[i][j] = new Label("ABC" + i + ":" + j);
        abc[i][j].setOnDragDropped(new DragDroppedEventHandler());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added some modification on the question, would you mind to take a look at it?

Comment: Sure! But I have some questions.... `why do you need thousands(100*100) of labels?` `Do you need separate handlers for each label?` I'm not sure but maybe you need to re-design your program before jumping into the code. I prefer to pick the `collection framework` instead of `(Label [][] abc = new Label[100][100])` .

Comment: Lets say, I am now having 100*100 labels, and I am going to drag drop a image on them. Actually you said do I need a separate handlers, then is there anyway to make a group handlers to handle all labels at once??

Comment: maybe in other words, is there any group handlers for this 2d label array?

Comment: Of course! If every label has the same nature, you can use the same handler to handle all the labels. `abc[i][j].setOnDragDropped(new DragDroppedEventHandler());` will set the same handler for all the labels. And your custom `DragDroppedEventHandler` class should have the logic to do so. And one more thing you can create your own class like `MyLabel(should be a subclass of Label)` where you can set `needed handlers` in the constructor as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but now if I use this: 
```Label target = abc[i][j];```
```target.setOnMouseEntererd ........... {target.setText("ABC");}; <-- this is not working```
And if I simply use ```abc[i][j].setOnMouseEntered... { abc[i][j].setText();}``` Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final will be warned in setText()

Comment: I think that in target.setOnMouseEntered using ```target``` again inside the anonymous inner function or lambda, they cannot regconize the ```target```. Since I have tried to getText setText and all of them seems not working.